# Нужны ли запятые в предложениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1) Знаю(,) что он вчера весь вечер готовил. 
2) Сейчас все работает(,) как часы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **Знаю, что он вчера весь вечер готовил.** - Сложноподчинённое предложение с придаточным изъяснительным. Запятая разделяет главное и придаточное предложения.

2) **Сейчас все работает как часы.** *Работает как часы* - фразеологизм, запятая не ставится.